# Best practices for using websockets in background service: WakeLock, WifiLock

Tags: android, websocket, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I've seen several questions about it, but didn't find a solid response.
I have an open web sockets connection in background for the whole day.

- Should I use cpu and wifi locks only for read/write operations?
- Does it handle the case of the phone deep sleep?
- Does incoming network packets wake up a device via both wifi and mobile networks?

  Does anyone have experience in this? I need to be sure that it works on devices of different manufactures.
  Thanks.